# How can i move data in one salesforce org to another salesforce org without affecting governor limits

Tags: integration

How can i move data in one salesforce org to another salesforce org without affecting governor limits.

What are the free softwares available??
pls help me out??

Comment: What type of orgs are you trying to move data between: Dev, Sandbox, Production?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [comparison chart](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AjFgFSBK8rxddHdvMUw1SWlDSjY3X1ZXUjdocFFDcWc&output=html)

As mentioned by Artur,Data Loader is the best. adding to it csv import - [workbench](https://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Workbench) is also good one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess best solution will be good, old CSV and Data Loader :)

Because there is no any automatic function(beside sandboxes) to move data.